# To ensure the current upgraded Debian testing has libc6 > 2.28

Tags: debian, upgrade, dependencies, libraries

Tried to have debian testing by upgrade it via apt package manager, so it was done

```
$ cat /etc/debian_version /etc/os-release 
bullseye/sid
PRETTY_NAME="Debian GNU/Linux bullseye/sid"
NAME="Debian GNU/Linux"
```

and listed all to ensure a newer libc6, but surprisingly it's not upgraded yet so then:

```
$ sudo apt upgrade libc6/testing
```

...

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libc-dev-bin : Depends: libc6 (< 2.29) but 2.31-9 is to be installed
 libc6 : Breaks: libgegl-0.4-0 (< 0.4.18) but 0.4.16-0.1~mx19+1 is to be installed
 libc6-dev : Depends: libc6 (= 2.28-10) but 2.31-9 is to be installed
 libgcc1:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.2.4) but it is not installable
```

How can it be not upgraded having libc6 > 2.28 which is (mostly) only 2.31 distributed now as printed above, although it's already full upgrade ?
Please help solve.

Comment: Most likely you are mixing Debian with non-Debian, like "MX Linux": this breaks your dependencies with libgegl etc. The usual link: https://wiki.debian.org/DontBreakDebian#Don.27t_make_a_FrankenDebian

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have set your `sources.list` correctly, here is how to override the non-debian repository (as said @A.B in [this comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/637105/to-ensure-the-current-upgraded-debian-testing-has-libc6-2-28#comment1193647_637105)) :

```
sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*

cat <<EOF |sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian/ unstable main
EOF
```

Then run:

```
sudo apt purge libgcc1 # not available in Sid
sudo apt update
sudo apt dist-upgrade
```